# Step by Step / Deep explain: The Power of (Co)Yoneda (preferably in scala) through Coroutines

Tags: scala, haskell, category-theory

some background code

```
/** FunctorStr: ∑ F[-]. (∏ A B. (A -> B) -> F[A] -> F[B]) */
trait FunctorStr[F[_]] { self =>
  def map[A, B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B]
}

trait Yoneda[F[_], A] { yo =>

  def apply[B](f: A => B): F[B]

  def run: F[A] =
    yo(x => x)

  def map[B](f: A => B): Yoneda[F, B] = new Yoneda[F, B] {
    def apply[X](g: B => X) = yo(f andThen g)
 }
}

object Yoneda {

  implicit def yonedafunctor[F[_]]: FunctorStr[({ type l[x] = Yoneda[F, x] })#l] =
    new FunctorStr[({ type l[x] = Yoneda[F, x] })#l] {
      def map[A, B](f: A => B): Yoneda[F, A] => Yoneda[F, B] =
        _ map f
    }

  def apply[F[_]: FunctorStr, X](x: F[X]): Yoneda[F, X] = new Yoneda[F, X] {
    def apply[Y](f: X => Y) = Functor[F].map(f) apply x
  }
} 



trait Coyoneda[F[_], A] { co =>

  type I

  def fi: F[I]

  def k: I => A

  final def map[B](f: A => B): Coyoneda.Aux[F, B, I] =
    Coyoneda(fi)(f compose k)

}

object Coyoneda {

  type Aux[F[_], A, B] = Coyoneda[F, A] { type I = B }

  def apply[F[_], B, A](x: F[B])(f: B => A): Aux[F, A, B] =
    new Coyoneda[F, A] {
     type I = B
     val fi = x
     val k = f
   }

  implicit def coyonedaFunctor[F[_]]: FunctorStr[({ type l[x] = Coyoneda[F, x] })#l] =
   new CoyonedaFunctor[F] {}

  trait CoyonedaFunctor[F[_]] extends FunctorStr[({type l[x] = Coyoneda[F, x]})#l] {
   override def map[A, B](f: A => B): Coyoneda[F, A] => Coyoneda[F, B] =
     x => apply(x.fi)(f compose x.k)
 }

  def liftCoyoneda[T[_], A](x: T[A]): Coyoneda[T, A] =
   apply(x)(a => a)

 }
```

Now I thought I understood yoneda and coyoneda a bit just from the types –
 i.e. 
 that they quantify / abstract over map fixed in some type constructor 
  F and some type a, to any type B returning F[B] or (Co)Yoneda[F, B]. 
Thus providing map fusion for free (? is this kind of like a cut rule for map ?).
But I see that Coyoneda is a functor for any type constructor F regardless of F being a Functor, 
 and that I don't fully grasp. 
Now I'm in a situation where I'm trying to define a Coroutine type, 
 (I'm looking at https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/coroutines-for-streaming/part-2-coroutines for the types to get started with)

```
case class Coroutine[S[_], M[_], R](resume: M[CoroutineState[S, M, R]])

sealed trait CoroutineState[S[_], M[_], R]

  object CoroutineState {
    case class Run[S[_], M[_], R](x: S[Coroutine[S, M, R]]) extends CoroutineState[S, M, R]
    case class Done[R](x: R) extends CoroutineState[Nothing, Nothing, R]

   class CoroutineStateFunctor[S[_], M[_]](F: FunctorStr[S]) extends 
      FunctorStr[({ type l[x] = CoroutineState[S, M, x]})#l] {
        override def map[A, B](f : A => B) : CoroutineState[S, M, A] => CoroutineState[S, M, B]
        =
        { ??? }
    }
  }
```

and I think that if I understood Coyoneda better I could leverage it to make S & M type constructors functors way easy, plus I see Coyoneda potentially playing a role in defining recursion schemes
 as the functor requirement is pervasive.

So how could I use coyoneda to make type constructors functors like for example coroutine state?
or something like a Pause functor ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The secret of Yoneda is that it "defers" the need for the `Functor` instance a bit. It's tricky at first because we can define `instance Functor (Yoenda f)` without using `f`'s `Functor` instance.

```
newtype Yoneda f a = Yoneda { runYoneda :: forall b . (a -> b) -> f b }

instance Functor (Yoneda f) where
  fmap f y = Yoneda (\ab -> runYoneda y (ab . f))
```

But the clever part about `Yoneda f a` is that it's supposed to be isomorphic to `f a`, however the witnesses to this isomorphism demand that `f` is a `Functor`:

```
toYoneda :: Functor f => f a -> Yoneda f a
toYoneda fa = Yoneda (\f -> fmap f fa)

fromYoneda :: Yoneda f a -> f a
fromYoneda y = runYoneda y id
```

So instead of appealing to the `Functor` instance for `f` during definition of the `Functor` instance for `Yoneda`, it gets "defered" to the construction of the `Yoneda` itself. Computationally, it also has the nice property of turning all `fmap`s into compositions with the "continuation" function `(a -> b)`.

The opposite occurs in `CoYoneda`. For instance, `CoYoneda f` is still a `Functor` whether or not `f` is

```
data CoYoneda f a = forall b . CoYoneda (b -> a) (f b)

instance Functor (CoYoneda f) where
  fmap f (CoYoneda mp fb) = CoYoneda (f . mp) fb
```

however now when we construct our isomorphism witnesses the `Functor` instance is demanded on the other side, when lowering `CoYoenda f a` to `f a`:

```
toCoYoneda :: f a -> CoYoneda f a
toCoYoneda fa = CoYoneda id fa

fromCoYoneda :: Functor f => CoYoneda f a -> f a
fromCoYoneda (CoYoneda mp fb) = fmap mp fb
```

Also we again notice the property that `fmap` is nothing more than composition along the eventual continuation.

So both of these are a way of "ignoring" a `Functor` requirement for a little while, especially while performing `fmap`s.

---

Now let's talk about this `Coroutine` which I think has a Haskell type like

```
data Coroutine s m r = Coroutine { resume :: m (St s m r) }
data St s m r = Run (s (Coroutine s m r)) | Done r

instance (Functor s, Functor m) => Functor (Coroutine s m) where
  fmap f = Coroutine . fmap (fmap f) . resume

instance (Functor s, Functor m) => Functor (St s m) where
  fmap f (Done r) = Done (f r)
  fmap f (Run s ) = Run (fmap (fmap f) s)
```

This instance this requires `Functor` instances for both the `s` and `m` types. Can we do away with them by using `Yoneda` or `CoYoneda`? Basically automatically:

```
data Coroutine s m r = Coroutine { resume :: CoYoneda m (St s m r) }
data St s m r = Run (CoYoneda s (Coroutine s m r)) | Done r

instance Functor (Coroutine s m) where
  fmap f = Coroutine . fmap (fmap f) . resume

instance Functor (St s m) where
  fmap f (Done r) = Done (f r)
  fmap f (Run s ) = Run (fmap (fmap f) s)
```

but now, given that I used `CoYoneda`, you'll need `Functor` instances for both `s` and `m` in order to extract `s` and `m` types out of your `Coroutine`. So what's the point?

```
mapCoYoneda :: (forall a . f a -> g a) -> CoYoneda f a -> CoYoneda g a
mapCoYoneda phi (CoYoneda mp fb) = CoYoneda mp (phi fb)
```

Well, if we have a natural transformation from our `f` to a `g` which does instantiate `Functor` then we can apply that at the end in order to extract our results. This structural mapping will only apply once and then, upon evaluating `fromCoYoneda`, the entire stack of composed `fmap`ped functions will hit the result.

---

Another reason why you might want to play with `Yoneda` is that it's sometimes possible to get `Monad` instances for `Yoneda f` even when `f` isn't even a `Functor`. For instance

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

-- YEndo ~ Yoneda Endo
data YEndo a = YEndo { yEndo :: (a -> b) -> (b -> b) }

instance Functor YEndo where
  fmap f y = YEndo (\ab -> yEndo y (ab . f))

instance Monad YEndo where
  return a = YEndo (\ab _ -> ab a)
  y >>= f  = YEndo (\ab b -> yEndo y (\a -> yEndo (f a) ab b) b)
```

where we get the definition of `Monad YEndo` by thinking of `YEndo` as a CPS transformed `Maybe` monad.

This kind of work obviously isn't useful if `s` must be left general, but can be beneficial if instantiating `Coroutine` concretely. This example was taken directly from Edward Kmett's post [Free Monads for Less 2](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/free-monads-for-less-2/).

Comment: is this how Codensity improves the performance of Free Monads as well ?

Comment: It's closely related—Yoneda, Density, Cont are all similar types. Instead of getting composition like `fmap`ing does in Yoneda, however, Codensity just right-associates all of the binds so that they don't have to keep traversing the whole Free monad.

Comment: To see this, try expanding `(m >>= n) >>= l` using the definition `m >>= k = Codensity (\c -> runCodensity m (\a -> runCodensity (k a) c))` where `Codensity` is of course `newtype Codensity f a = Codensity { runCodensity :: forall r . (a -> f r) -> f r }` or kind of `type Codensity f a = forall r . ContT r f a`

Comment: Codensity is a bit "too big" for the job, e.g., Codensity of Reader is isomorphic to State, not Reader. Edward Kmett's Free Monads for Less 2 contains this result as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to talk competently about Kan extensions at large. Sorry

Comment: `YEndo` uses didn't kind-check: I added one type param to YEndo, ensuring that YEndo ~ Yoneda Endo, I hope I didn't get this wrong.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I love your explanation of (Co)Yoneda, because you mention that they defer the need for the functor instance.

Comment: @Mzk I can't read your code snippet because some code was taken as markup... underscores?

Comment: @Blaisorblade here's my comment rewritten
I have questions about this and Kan extensions but I'm unsure how to best phrase one to start a constructive dialogue... Something about yoneda and Kan extensions particularly yoneda to Ran and coyoneda to Lan, there seems to be an direct ascension in abstraction levels i.e
      
      `Ran[F[_], K[_], X] { def apply[B]:(A => F[B])=> X[B] }`

      `Codensity[F[_], A] { def apply[B]: (A => F[B]) => F[B] }`

      `Yoneda[F[_], A] { def apply[B]: (A => B) => F[B] }`

Comment: @Mzk: Indeed, Codensity and Yoneda are (different) right Kan extensions. For instance, `type Yoneda = Ran Identity` (http://comonad.com/reader/2008/kan-extensions/).
And `Codensity f = Ran f f` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-4.0.3/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html). It's easy to see the equality of types, but it's comforting to see somebody competent (Edward Kmett) confirm it's not an accident.
But I'm not competent enough to talk about Kan extensions either: You better study Kmett's posts and/or ask new questions.