# How to specify context bound for a type parameter of overridden method (Cats Monad)

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

I know the title is a mouthful so let me explain.
I want to implement custom monad `FileM` by using the Cats Monad trait.
At the same time I want to define context bound for the type parameter so that
`FileM` can only be used on types for which an instance of the `Show` typeclass exists.

I've tried the following:

```scala
case class FileM[T : Show] private (value: T)

object FileM {
  implicit val fileM: Monad[FileM] =
    new Monad[FileM] {

      override def pure[A](x: A): FileM[A] = {
        new FileM[A](x) // could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.Show[A]
      }

      override def flatMap[A, B](fa: FileM[A])(f: A => FileM[B]): FileM[B] = ???

      override def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => FileM[Either[A, B]]): FileM[B] = ???
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the context bound to the `pure` method type parameter:

```scala
override def pure[A: Show](x: A): FileM[A] = {
  new FileM[A](x)
}
```

But this changes the signature so it no longer overrides the `pure` method from the `Monad` trait.

How can I add context bound to type `A` in this example?
I'm using scala `2.13.8` and `cats-core:2.8.0`

Comment: If you add a context bound to `FileM` then `FileM` is not a `Monad`. You violate the contract of type class `Monad`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113417/numeric-map-over-with-functor

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraint-classes-0.5.1/docs/Control-ConstraintClasses.html

Comment: You can ask for the evidence of show when generating the monad insatnce

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Do you mean something like what cats does for Future’s ExecutionContext? If yes, I don’t think that would be possible here.

Comment: @AminMal yeah that is precisely what I mean, it would not be possible with the code as it is right now, but maybe with some changes. Otherwise is not possible.

Comment: Can you also explain why you want all the instances to be showable? ( if you want) there might be a better way to do that.

Comment: @AminMal, for educational purposes, I'm trying to define a monad `FileM` that persists the contained value to a file after each `map`. Just like IDE saves a file on every keystroke. I wanted to save the value as string, hence the requirement for `Show`.

Comment: https://ku-fpg.github.io/practice/constrainedTypeClassInstances/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192481/implementing-functor-map-for-class-tagged-arguments-only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725356/how-to-implement-functordataset

Comment: http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/2011/09/10/constraint-kinds-for-ghc/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238411/functor-instance-for-gadts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000465/step-by-step-deep-explain-the-power-of-coyoneda-preferably-in-scala-throu https://medium.com/@olxc/yoneda-and-coyoneda-trick-f5a0321aeba4

Comment: So generally there are two solutions: constrained/restricted/tagged type classes (like functor, monad) and Coyoneda (i.e. free functors)/free monads.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I also immediately thought about [that particular coyoneda trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725356/how-to-implement-functordataset), but genuinely wondering how you found it ;;; @jcz Re _"I'm trying to define a monad FileM that persists the contained value to a file after each map"_ - Can it then satisfy that `map(f).map(g)` = `map(g.compose(f))`? If not, then it's not a functor, and consequentially not a monad. I think one could do something like this with Coyoneda, but I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Looking for one's answer that you remember can be tricky at SO :) Isn't Coyoneda not enough? OP wants a monad, not functor. So free monads?

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yes, indeed, Coyoneda seems to be "too flat" / lacking a way to accumulate `flatMap`s (i.e. one would just re-invent something like a free monad). But, again, it would be a somewhat "distorted" free monad, with strange constraints on the `map`, right? Alongside with the `FlatMap`s, it would also accumulate some kind of `SaveToFile[A : Show]`-gizmos along the way. This seems like too high of a price for a little bit of syntactic convenience of doing the `map`ping and saving at once. I somehow feel that it's better to just make the saving step explicit.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin *"But, again, it would be a somewhat "distorted" free monad, with strange constraints on the map, right?"* Not sure. Coyoneda makes any type constructor a functor, right? (And context bound doesn't forbid that). And free monad makes any functor a monad, right? (And we already have a functor).

Comment: @DmytroMitin I was referring to the requirement that the OP mentioned in the 8th comment above: _"persists the contained value to a file after each map"_ - for this (assuming that "persisting" means having a `Show` instance), each `map`-invocation would somehow have to accept some extra information (`Show`) every time, that would make it just incompatible with standard `Monad`-interface altogether, regardless of the number of wrappers. But then, again, _"after each map"_ is somehow ill-defined anyway, so I'm still not sure what the OP actually wants.

Comment: I'm currently wondering: wouldn't it be fun to define something more heterogeneous than a monad: some kind of `Map[F[_], A, B] { def map(a: F[A], f: A => B): F[B]`-typeclass which is _explicitly parameterized_ by `A` and `B` (instead of just by `F[_]`), and then have _two separate_ instances, one high-priority for the cases where there is a `Show[B]`, and one low-priority for the cases where there isn't. Not sure yet what I'm actually after here, will take a look tomorrow.